# are there an efficent way to sort a parametermap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a parameter map incoming from a post in a web form. The problem I have is that I want to have the key values sorted.

I have two keys incoming `j_idt40:j_idt41:0:score` and `j_idt40:j_idt41:0:scoreID` These I would either want to find without resorting to loop through the map for every row I iterate again. Is there a better way to do this?

```
j_idt40:j_idt69 = Uppdatera
j_idt40:j_idt41:3:score = 200
j_idt40:j_idt41:0:scoreID = 1
j_idt40:j_idt41:4:scoreID = 
j_idt40:j_idt41:3:scoreID = 4
j_idt40:j_idt41:2:scoreID = 3
j_idt40:j_idt41:0:score = 203
j_idt40:j_idt41:2:score = 200
j_idt40:j_idt41:1:score = 200
j_idt40 = j_idt40
j_idt40:j_idt41:4:score = 800
j_idt40:j_idt41:1:scoreID = 2
```

Comment: can you explain how are we suppose to understand the sorting? base on what? For example which is bigger: j_idt40:j_idt41:1:scoreID = 2 or j_idt40:j_idt41:4:score = 800

Comment: if you got a un-sorted map (say hashmap), you want to do sorting, even if you don't explicitly loop through, the codes behind the  method/library you used will do that anyway.

Comment: j_idt40:j_idt41:0:scoreID = 1, j_idt40:j_idt41:0:score = 203 maps to each other as you can see from the name before the last colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural sorting you need to write your own comparator. The existing comparators in jdk will fail on the following scenario.

```
TreeMap<String,String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
treeMap.put("key1", "value"); 
treeMap.put("key2", "value");
treeMap.put("key20", "value");
treeMap.put("key10", "value");
treeMap.put("key11", "value");      
treeMap.put("key21", "value");
```

The sorting will happen like this.

key1,key10,key11,key2,key20,key21

Natural sorting is implemented in Java 8 see [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--)

or

Use apache commons [ComparatorUtils.NATURAL_COMPARATOR](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ComparatorUtils.html#NATURAL_COMPARATOR)

Answer (score 0):

will [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) help you in this regard ?

TreeMap Keeps everything sorted. This is built-in class in Java collection API.

You can use this constructor to convert your map to sorted map.

```
TreeMap(Map  m)  // this is from 'java.util.TreeMap'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull all the Map.Entries out into a list, sort that, then loop through it once.  You've have to make a Comparitor for Map.Entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the keys like this:

```
    Collection<?> keys = params.keySet();
    String[] array = keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(array);
```

Or if you want the entries of the map to be ordered, you can achieve this by inserting them into a `TreeMap`.  When you iterate the TreeMap's key set they come out in order.

Which approach is more "efficient" depends on what measure of efficiency you are talking about (CPU, memory, developer time).

It also depends on how often various things are performed by your application.  For example:

- lookup, insert and delete operations are on average `O(1)` for a `HashMap` and `O(logN)` for a TreeMap
- iterating a TreeMap's key set is `O(N)`
- extracting and sorting a Hashmap's keys is `O(NlogN)`